# How to check if a user has a role from another Discord server

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So my bot DinoCord has Economy features and I want to lower cooldowns for a specific role ("Premium"). The thing is I don't know how to check if a user has a role across all servers.

Currently we use this if

```js
(!message.member.roles.some(role => role.id === "678114167902830610"))
```

but that only checks in our support server where the role is at, and nowhere else. So my question is is there a way to check if a user has a role from my [support server](https://discord.gg/VmACrv5) in all other servers?

**Here is a gif of it.**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Discord.js v11 (which is what you seem to be using):

```js
// your support server
const supportGuild = client.guilds.get('673691776317390868')
const member = supportGuild.members.get(message.author.id)
const hasPremium = member ? member.roles.get('678114167902830610') : false
```

For v12 and v13:

```js
// your support server
const supportGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('673691776317390868')
const member = supportGuild.members.cache.get(message.author.id)
const hasPremium = member ? member.roles.cache.get('678114167902830610') : false
```